# How to overwrite updated repository

Tags: git

I'm receiving the error `Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:` as I'm trying to push my files but the repo has already been pushed by someone. The only change to that repo was couple lines to a file, however, I want to overwrite that merge and use my local files as the new, updated repo.

So basically how do I push my local changes so I can overwrite the merge?

Sorry if it sounds confusing, let me know if I need to clarify it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you haven't committed yet. If you commit then pull, git will guide you through a clean merge, which you can then push without a problem.

Alternatively, if that isn't your problem, you can force push. **However** a forced push is a **destructive** operation, that says "hey ignore whatever's up there and make it look like my local." You will lose history this way, and you should never, ever do this on a public repository.

My recommendation would be to go through a merge. If you've only changed a few lines, then doing the merge shouldn't be too painful. This is better because it keeps all of your history.

Comment: I did commit but I got this when I pull from origin master
`CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in .../main.css
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.`

git didn't show any steps I can take.

Comment: Aha, alright. If you run 'git status' you can check where you're at. You should be in the middle of a merge. Git will have marked up your main.css file with markings that have a bunch of equals (=) in them and labels. Edit your file to match how you want it, remove the markings, then commit the result and push and you should be good.

Comment: I see that. When I did `git status` it says "You have unmerged paths." and it shows me the file. Should I just `git add <file>` to that file? 
Or should I be looking at my main.css file with the markings and do something to it?

Comment: You need to edit the file to finish the merge. Git wasn't able to merge your file automatically, so it instead marked it up with the location(s), what your changes at each place are, and what the changes you pulled are. Since you changed just a few lines doing it manually shouldn't be too painful. Once you have that all set, you can add and commit the file.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to `commit` to save your local changes. `pull` to get the new changes and merge in. `push` to update with your new merged in changes.

After your pull you will probably have merge conflicts. Great! This is your chance to edit the files to be how you want them. This is a nice help doc on how to do this: https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/

Comment: When I pull, wouldn't it overwrite my local changes? Or am I missing some steps here?

Comment: Not after you make a `commit`

Comment: I did commit but I got this when pull
`CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in .../main.css
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.`

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/ this should explain how to resolve the conflict.